# Switch columns and row on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transpose

I have a pandas dataframe, and I need to "switch" row and columns. (transpose ? pivot ? melt ? no idea how is it called) :

Let's say I have 2 references, each reference has 4 steps, each step has 3 variables

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'ref': ['ref1', 'ref1', 'ref1', 'ref1', 'ref2', 'ref2', 'ref2', 'ref2'],
                   'step': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'var_1': [5, 7, 7, 9, 12, 9, 87, 90],
                   'var_2': [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 9, 12, 9],
                   "var_3": [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 9, 12, 9]})
```

[image]

I want to transform this df to this form :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ref': ['ref1', 'ref2'],
>                    'step 1 - var_1': [5, 12],
>                    'step 1 - var_2': [11, 6],
>                    'step 1 - var_3': [11, 6],
>                    'step 2 - var_1': [7, 12],
>                    'step 2 - var_2': [8, 9],
>                    'step 2 - var_3': [8, 9]})
```

[image]

On the df below, I have tried the methods (and they worked):

```
(df
.pivot_wider(
    index='ref', 
    names_from='step',  
    values_from = ['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3'],
    names_glue = "step {step} - {_value}")
.sort_index(axis=1)
) 

# and also
df_out = df.pivot(index='ref', columns='step').sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df_out.columns = [f'step {j} - {i}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
```

The actual df looks like :

[image]

But they don't work on my actual df, I have the error code : "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Last Edit : the "unique ID" of my df had duplicant, now it's working, thank you all for your answer. I learnt a lot of new stuff today :)

Thank you in advance,
Best

edit : format and images

Comment: How does the input correspond to the output?

Comment: From the output columns, it *sounds* like you might want to `df.explode('step')` and then `rename()`, but the row values do not correspond to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is with [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) from [pyjnanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), to abstract the column renaming via the `names_glue` parameter:

```py
# pip insall pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df
.pivot_wider(
    index='ref', 
    names_from='step',  
    values_from = ['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3'],
    names_glue = "step {step} - {_value}")
.sort_index(axis=1)
) 
    ref  step 1 - var_1  step 1 - var_2  step 1 - var_3  ...  step 3 - var_3  step 4 - var_1  step 4 - var_2  step 4 - var_3
0  ref1               5              11              11  ...              10               9               6               6
1  ref2              12               6               6  ...              12              90               9               9

[2 rows x 13 columns]
```

`names_glue` allows a combination of the `values_from` and `names_from` parameters - in the code above `{step}` is the names_from argument, while `{_value}` is a placeholder for `values_from`

If we stick strictly to your output, then a filter should be executed on the `step` column  for only values less than 3:

```py
(df
.loc[df.step < 3]
.pivot_wider(
    index='ref', 
    names_from='step', 
    names_glue = "step {step} - {_value}")
.sort_index(axis=1)
) 
    ref  step 1 - var_1  step 1 - var_2  step 1 - var_3  step 2 - var_1  step 2 - var_2  step 2 - var_3
0  ref1               5              11              11               7               8               8
1  ref2              12               6               6               9               9               9
```

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I want to achieve, thx you :)


I got this error when I run it on my data : "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape".
I tried to drop other columns to avoid interference but it won't work, any idea ?

Comment: you might have to create another column that makes your data unique - kindly update your question to reflect the duplicate entries, with expected output

Comment: I have updated my question, I have created a colone "ref" which will be unique once the transformation is complete.

Comment: Kindly share text, not pics. Share the excel file instead if U csn

Answer (score 2):

Try this using the new "walrus" operator in a one-liner:

```
(df_new := df.set_index(['ref', 'step']).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1))\
    .set_axis([f'step {j} - {i}' for i, j in df_new.columns], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      step 1 - var_1  step 1 - var_2  step 1 - var_3  step 2 - var_1  step 2 - var_2  step 2 - var_3  step 3 - var_1  step 3 - var_2  step 3 - var_3  step 4 - var_1  step 4 - var_2  step 4 - var_3
ref                                                                                                                                                                                                 
ref1               5              11              11               7               8               8               7              10              10               9               6               6
ref2              12               6               6               9               9               9              87              12              12              90               9               9
```

Details:

- `set_index` with columns ref and step
- `unstack` step to move into columns
- Order you columns uinsg `sort_index`
- flatten multiindex dataframe column headers using `set_axis` and list
  comprehension with f-string formatting

Alternative way with same out put with order as above,

```
df_out = df.pivot(index='ref', columns='step').sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df_out.columns = [f'step {j} - {i}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I have this error when I run the code : "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" do you know why ?

Comment: Yes, you have multiple entries with ref and step, you'll need to do a groupby or pivot_table with some sort of aggregation to handle multiple entries.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df[df.step<3].set_index(['ref','step']).unstack()
```

output:

```
     var_1    var_2    var_3   
step     1  2     1  2     1  2
ref                            
ref1     5  7    11  8    11  8
ref2    12  9     6  9     6  9
```

Comment: It's a good approach, but needs to change the column headers to match OP's request.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use [df.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html?highlight=pivot#pandas.DataFrame.pivot). You can choose the `index='ref'` and `columns='step'`:

```
new = df.pivot(index='ref', columns='step')
```

The resulting table has a multi-index for `ref` and a multi-column. The multi-column has the step and var information, so we can use that to make the new column headers. Finally, we can reset the index:

```
new.columns = [f'step {x[1]} - {x[0]}' for x in new.columns]
new = new.reset_index()
```

Comment: Hi SNygard, I have tried your method, but I have an error code : "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". I edited my question with details if it can help :)